# How do I prevent a child string from ending the parent string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, escaping

## Description:

I have a very simple button that I want to call a javascript function when clicked. Everything works fine with the function and the button with the exception of one issue that I can't seem to overcome.

The Javascript function copies a string in to the clipboard to be easily pasted for the user. The string is pulled in from another area that is free text for the user to put in what ever they want. However, if the user adds a double quote, it escapes the parent string.

## Example:

Example of working code button:

```
<button id="Demo" onclick="copytoclipboard('some text to copy goes here')">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

Example of when the button will not work:

```
<button id="Demo" onclick="copytoclipboard('some "text" to copy goes here')">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

As you may be able to see, the first double quotation mark is ending the parent string.

## What I have tried:

So far I have tried escaping the double quote but this doesn't appear to work due to the fact that it is a child string.

Example:

```
<button id="Demo" onclick="copytoclipboard('some \"text\" to copy goes here')">Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

## Back to the question:

How do I prevent any double quotes in the child string the ending the parent string that is in turn preventing my onclick function to run?

Comment: You should make a listener for click and avoid the problem of exposing whole unescaped text into the html. have you tried a JavaScript version of that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't fully understand what you mean. I know what I listener is but I'm unsure how to put that in to practise here. (I'm mainly a PHP guy)

Comment: you can simply use &quot; instead of the double quotes. I dont think you have many options when it comes to putting the string inside the tag directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This breaks down to: you're looking to escape data (doesn't matter whether plain text or javascript) in an XML (or more specifically HTML) attribute value.

You'll find plenty of info about that - in this case the easiest way is to escape the doublequote char (") via `&quot;`

```html
<button onclick="alert(&quot;foobar&quot;);">Click me</button>
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly then I would need to replace any double quotes in the string with "$quot;"?

Comment: I tested this by replacing all double quotes with &quot; and it works a charm!

Comment: By the way, just to add it to the answer: apostrophe's entity is `&apos;` (or `&#39;` in HTML-code).

Comment: You mentioned you're generating the output via php? Would probably be a good idea to wrap the attribute value in htmlspecialchars(...), to be safe!

Answer (score 0):

The way that you tried escaping the double quote was almost perfect but you need to do it like this:

```
<button id="Demo" onclick='copytoclipboard("some \"text\" to copy goes here")'>Copy to Clipboard</button>
```

You can learn more about escaping special characters in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp).

Comment: As far as I can tell all you have done there is replace the parent double quote for a single quote. However, the issue now will be if the user puts in a single quote as that will escape the parent string will it not?

Comment: @Petay87, is the content inside the `copytoclipboard()` a string or a variable?

Comment: it's a php string which can consist of absolutely anything the user inputs in to a free text field. Tiax's answer works perfectly for me in this case.